# C# read a text file and search for string

Tags: c#, string, text

In C# how can I open the text file , search for string "mystring" and if string is there then set variable **Vara** = 1 else **Vara**= 0 .

Thanks in advance

Comment: So let me ask you this: **What have you tried?**

Comment: This question does `NOT` show any research effort: http://www.google.com.au/search?q=read+a+text+file+and+search+for+string+c%23

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Quick & dirty using [`System.IO.File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx):

```
int Vara = File.ReadAllText(path).Contains("mystring") ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Very quick.. very dirty :P

Comment: @user1570210 in the above code `path` is a string variable...

Answer (score 2):

won't do all your exercise to leave you some fun, but here a way to start:

to get all text of a file into a string variable try this:

```
using System.IO;

string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\file.txt");
```

then here to check if your string is inside:

```
bool present = fileContent.IndexOf("mystring") >= 0;
```

Comment: Sorry guys i know its very simple , but this a very very small piece of a complex ETL process.